# How to correctly implement dynamic prototype cells in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I, previously, had an issue where my UITextView was incapable of functioning, entirely. Since then, another user has taken a lot of time to help me solve this issue. I can say that it was successfully resolved. However, I now have an additional issue. When attempting to utilize properties of a prototype cell, which I’ve already made a UITextViewCell custom class for, as well as linked all the appropriate items, I run into an issue where the properties of the cell are being ignored. Only one property every shows, the dimensions are incorrect and the property that shows doesn’t have correct formatting. If you have time, can someone do a step by step, possibly with images, detailing EXACTLY what to do to make a custom table view cell that initializes correctly? You can assume that the table view and accompanying arrays etc. are already correctly initialized. Thank you.

Comment: *"the properties of the cell are being ignored"* ... **What** properties are being ignored? If you search (on google, for instance) for the terms: `objective c uitableview custom cell`, you can find an incredible number of examples, tutorials, etc, complete with images.

Comment: I fixed one major issue, now. So, I can assume that only one property of the cell is being ignored. This property is the height. Although I’ve justified this in the storyboard, the cell produced in the built version of the application contains all properties apart from the height, causing me to be unable to see content that is lower down in the prototype cell, which was meant to have a greater height.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout / constraints with dynamic row height? Or are you "setting the row height" in your storyboard, but *not* setting it in code?

Comment: Hmm, I don’t use constraints. So I was only dragging the slider for the prototype cell up and down, which triggers a property to change to custom and be given a higher value than the default of 44. Are you saying I MUST define this within the code? How do I do this?

Comment: Are your rows all the same height?

Comment: They should be, because I’ve defined the height in the single prototype cell I’m using as 110 points, therefore all rows should have a 110 point height, as they correspond to the same properties as the prototype cell. However, they, instead, all just show the default row size of 44 points...

Comment: And... in your storyboard, did you set the `Row Height` value on your TableView ***and*** on the Cell itself?

Comment: I didn’t set it on the view, thanks for helping with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set both values...

With the Table View selected - note the Value for `Row Height`:

[image]

With the Cell selected - note the Value for `Row Height`:

[image]